# n-tier c# applicaiton with BAL and DAL methods with exact same names ( signatures etc.. )

Tags: c#, data-access-layer, n-tier-architecture, business-logic-layer

I'm on a project in which I'm failing to see the point of how a previous developer made decisions.

1. same exact method names in DAL and BAL
2. static is EVERYWHERE
3. what should i do with New methods to follow best practices?

example of existing code:

**Calling appliction (could be console app or web app etc..  agnostic )**

```
DataSet DS = CreditMgr.GetCreditRqstInfo(ddlGEO.Text);
```

**BAL**

```
public class CreditMgr
{
   public static DataSet GetCreditRqstInfo(String GeoID)
    {
        try
        {
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            DS = CreditIntfDB.GetCreditRqstInfo(GeoID);
            return DS;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

**DAL**

```
public class CreditIntfDB
{
     public static DataSet GetCreditRqstInfo(String GeoID)
    {
        try
        {
            Database DB = new SqlDatabase(Common.ConnectionString);
            String SQLCommand = Common.SPGetRqstInfo;
            DbCommand DBCommand = DB.GetStoredProcCommand(SQLCommand);
            DBCommand.CommandTimeout = Common.CommandTimeOut;
            DB.AddInParameter(DBCommand, "@a_geo_id", DbType.String, GeoID);
            DataSet DS = new DataSet();
            DB.LoadDataSet(DBCommand, DS, new String[] { "CreditRqstInfo" });

            return DS;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, the whole point is to have layers of separation, but when the same method names are being used , and static,  and each are simply doing the same exact thing with passing in string and returning a **DataSet**  has  "code smell" to me

Suggestions on better ways?

Comment: Even though the names are same if you could Suffix with `BAL` or `DAL` would be easy to identify. I am sure namespace shows whether a class belonged to `BAL` or `DAL` .

Comment: Yes, the code is bad, but what's your question exactly? `catch (Exception ex) { throw ex; }` ughhh.

Comment: This may be more appropriate for [Stack Exchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). In general I agree with you - layers for the sake of layers is not good design. Each layer needs a purpose; every class needs a responsibility. If you don't have any meaningful business logic, then the BAL may not be valuable for your case.

Comment: thank you all  ,  yes  same method names and signatures,   static,  just does not scream of a good pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to standard Object-Oriented Programming (OOP) design, your BAL classes should represent "things" that have some real world business meaning. Instead of having a CreditMgr that has a static method to get a CreditRqst, create a class CreditRequest that stores its own data (e.g. the DataSet), and preferably wraps it in some business-friendly manner (e.g. List of CreditLine or List of Account).

From there, you can either implement the Get method inside of CreditRequest, or you can turn CreditMgr into a service object (such as "CreditBureau", "Bank", "AccountsDesk", etc.), that has a method that takes a String GeoID and returns a CreditRequest.

In addition, using strings as keys (e.g. in GeoID) is smelly as well. Can you come up with something a little more strongly typed? You could create a class GeoID that enforces requirements (such as maximum length, allowable characters, checksum requirements, etc.)